# Change look and feel in WPF application?

Tags: java, wpf, swing, look-and-feel

Is there easy way to change look and feel of your WPF app, just like in Java Swing?

I can change it manually, by adopting manually crated styles on various controls...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I have well understood the question but in [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WPF%20Themes&referringTitle=Home) there are some themes that allows you to change quickly your application interface.

Answer (score 1):

> I can change it manually, by adopting
> manually crated styles on various
> controls...

Depends how smart you were developing it.

Normal WPF controls have no look at all - to start with. They use INHERITED STYLES, which you can override. If you override them manually, as you said, on various controls, you basically willfully ignore the inheritance. Just put in a new style catalogue at the root of the inheritance tree.