# Setting Look and Feel

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following LAFs ("Look And Feel" ,From Java's Swing) in two different projects :

Type 1 :

[image]

Type 2 :

[image]

I would like to know how I can switch between these and other LAFs.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean GUI controls? So each button, drop drop menu etc is a separate control?

Comment: No I mean the way they look. The first one has more "3D" buttons whereas #2 has more "2D" buttons.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest, most maintainable method that I'm aware of for quickly swapping in different visual styles is to use Styles in an external ResourceDictionary. For the example below you would create a new solution folder called 'Skins', then add a new class called 'MainSkin.xaml'.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Skins/MainSkin.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlockV1}" Text="This is some text." />
</Grid>
```

Skins\MainSkin.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style x:Key="TextBlockV1" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Comic Sans MS" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="TextBlockV2" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Courier New" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30" />
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="TextBlockV3" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Times New Roman" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="8" />
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score -1):

[Change look and feel in WPF application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470081/change-look-and-feel-in-wpf-application)

This directs you to [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WPF%20Themes&referringTitle=Home) which shows you how to set themes in the xml for a page.

Comment: But both the projects' App.xaml have their `<Application.Resources>` empty. So then why are their themes different?

Comment: Generally, I would guess that they're running on different computers or were made on different computers. WPFs default styling comes from the desktop theme (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Those (fairly ancient) themes are severely broken. I'd strongly recommend against trying to use them. Further, just slinging a link in doesn't make for a good answer - if you think the question has a duplicate then mark it so.